# Separating denominator and numerator inputs when given a slash c++

Tags: c++, input, istream, fractions

Im relatively new to C++ and I was wondering if I could get help with a problem that ive been having. Im given an input as either a fraction of type A/B or an integer value. I need to separate the A and B values so I can put them in the fracnum and fracdnum variables. The problem comes when im given an integer value. Here is my code:

```
istream& operator >>(istream& in,  Fraction& frac){
    char slash = '/' ;
    int fracnum;
    int fracdnum;
    int peekchar;
in >>fracnum;
if(in >> slash){
    in >>fracdnum;
}
else{
    in.putback(slash);
    fracdnum = 1;
}

    frac = Fraction(fracnum, fracdnum);
    return in;
    }
```

I do not know how to split the two fractions and also handle integers.

edit*****

Ive tried using the scanf method but it still isnt working, here is my try at it, anybody notice anything wrong with it?

```
istream& operator >>(istream& in,  Fraction& frac){
int fracdnum;
int fracnum;
int num_read = scanf("%d/%d", &fracnum, &fracdnum);
if( num_read ==1){
    fracdnum=1;
Fraction(fracnum,fracdnum);
}
else if (num_read == 2){
    Fraction(fracnum,fracdnum);
}

    return in;
    }
```

This is the test file i use for the program:

```
    // Test input, exception and +=:
    Fraction sum(0);
    Fraction fin;
    cout << "\nSumming fractions. Enter fractions as \"1/2\" or just enter a single integer." << endl;
    cout << "Enter zero to end the summation:" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Enter a fraction to add to sum: ";
        try {
            cin >> fin;
            sum += fin;
        } catch (FractionException &e) {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        }
    } while (fin != 0);
    cout << "Sum is: " << sum << endl;


    return 0;

} // end main
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this is a case where `scanf` is just easier:

```
int num_read = scanf("%d/%d", &fracnum, &fracdnum);
if(num_read == 1) {
    // scanf read one number
    fracdnum = 1;
} else if(num_read == 2) {
    // scanf read two numbers
} else {
    // scanf read nothing: fail
}
```

Comment: how would this handle integers without a slash

Comment: It isnt working this is how the output looks, it freezes at enter zero to end smumation:   
Summing fractions. Enter fractions as "1/2" or just enter a single integer.
Enter zero to end the summation:
3
Enter a fraction to add to sum: Sum is: 0/1

Comment: @harmanlitt: Try `getline` and then `sscanf` on that.  That prevents `scanf` from mucking up input that doesn't match when looking for a `/`.  It also prevents `scanf` from reading from a different stream than the one passed to your `operator>>`.

Comment: @harmanlitt: Ben is right, if you are doing this as an interactive application (which was not clear from your original question) then you want to read the whole line, then parse it.

Comment: how would you use getline on sscanf? im sorry, im still relatively new to this.

Comment: @harmanlitt: `getline` into a `std::string`, then `sscanf` the string's `.c_str()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `scanf` attempt, yes there are lots of things wrong.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Fraction& frac)
{
    int fracdnum;
    int fracnum;
```

So far everything is ok, except spelling.

```
    int num_read = scanf("%d/%d", &fracnum, &fracdnum);
```

Ooops, you just read from `stdin` instead of `in`.

```
    if( num_read ==1){
        fracdnum=1;
        Fraction(fracnum,fracdnum);
```

Ouch, you created a temporary Fraction object and threw it away again.

```
    }
    else if (num_read == 2){
        Fraction(fracnum,fracdnum);
```

same problem

```
    }

    return in;
}
```

This should be better:

```
istream& operator >>(istream& in,  Fraction& frac)
{
   int fracdenom;
   int fracnum;

   std::string inputline;
   if (getline(in, inputline)) {
       int num_read = sscanf(inputline.c_str(), "%d/%d", &fracnum, &fracdenom);
       if (num_read > 0) {
           if (num_read < 2) {
               fracdenom=1;
           }
           frac = Fraction(fracnum,fracdenom);
       }
       else {
           in.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
       }
   }
   return in;
}
```

If you want spaces to work as terminators, use `in >> inputline` instead of `getline(in, inputline)`.

Comment: I tried this way , it almost worked! The only issue im having now is when i type '0'  to end the summation and display the summed value the answer comes out to 0/0. Added a cout after the sum += fin; to check what the sum value was. THe values are adding but when i type 0 the summation goes to 0/0 and the output sum is shown as 0/0

Comment: @harmanlitt: Try printing the sum each time you add a new fraction to it.  Probably you have an error with `+=`.

Comment: Added a cout after the sum += fin; to check what the sum value was. THe values are adding but when i type 0 the summation goes to 0/0 and the output sum is shown as 0/0

Comment: @harmanlitt: I suppose your common-denominator code is failing, when you add `0/0`.  That sounds like a whole new question, though, because it is unrelated to input.